# How to handle post method in Jmeter for load testing?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I want to perform load testing post method using jmeter on application server. I performed load testing many times get request using jmeter on application server. I don't know how to how to handle post method in jmeter for load testing?.

POST HTTP REQUEST:

```
Content-Type for POST is "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

    REQUEST : http://localhost:8080/configserver/execute?command=Login

POST Parameter:

    data={
      "email": "user@domain.com",
      "password": "12345"
    }

Output:

    {
      "status_code": "0",
      "status_message": "",
      "result": {
        "user_id": "1",
        "session_token": "abcd"
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Configuration would be the following;

[image: Config]

Read this:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request

And read this tutorial:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-adv-web-test-plan.html