# How to send double quotes for an parametrized attribute in Json body

Tags: json, jmeter, http-post

I am trying to send a post request with body data where one of the attribute, which passes a list of numbers, requires to be inside the double quotes. I am using something like this **[${id}]** but it sends the number as [123] when I want it to be sent as ["123"], I have tried several methods to add quotes inside and outside of the curley braces but didn't work. Please advise

Thanks

Comment: It should work with ["${id}"] Read this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25585197/how-to-handle-post-method-in-jmeter-for-load-testing

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax would be `["${id}"]`

[image]

You can check what exactly is being sent using [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener:

[image]

Also assuming you're sending a [JSON payload](http://json.org/) you might also need to add a [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager/) and configure it to send [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) header with the value of [`application/json`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#MIME_type)